# not able to submit workflow in oozie

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, oozie, oozie-coordinator, oozie-workflow

I am running a workflow in oozie which contains a shell script for transferring files from one s3 location to another.

I was getting `output data limit exceeds` error.hence I increased `oozie.action.max.output.data` value and i restarted the oozie using `sudo /sbin/stop oozie` `sudo /sbin/start oozie`
After restarting i am not able to submit any workflows I am getting error :

> "{ "traceback": [ [
>   "/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py",
>   112, "get_response", "response = wrapped_callback(request,
>   *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)" ], [ "/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.7.egg/django/db/transaction.py",
>   371, "inner", "return func(*args, **kwargs)" ], [
>   "/usr/lib/hue/apps/oozie/src/oozie/decorators.py", 113, "decorate",
>   "return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)" ], [
>   "/usr/lib/hue/apps/oozie/src/oozie/decorators.py", 75, "decorate",
>   "return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)" ], [
>   "/usr/lib/hue/apps/oozie/src/oozie/views/editor2.py", 373,
>   "submit_workflow", "return _submit_workflow_helper(request, workflow,
>   submit_action=reverse('oozie:editor_submit_workflow',
>   kwargs={'doc_id': workflow.id}))" ], [
>   "/usr/lib/hue/apps/oozie/src/oozie/views/editor2.py", 428,
>   "_submit_workflow_helper", "'is_oozie_mail_enabled':
>   _is_oozie_mail_enabled(request.user)" ], [ "/usr/lib/hue/apps/oozie/src/oozie/views/editor2.py", 435,
>   "_is_oozie_mail_enabled", "oozie_conf = api.get_configuration()" ], [
>   "/usr/lib/hue/desktop/libs/liboozie/src/liboozie/oozie_api.py", 319,
>   "get_configuration", "resp = self._root.get('admin/configuration',
>   params)" ], [
>   "/usr/lib/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/lib/rest/resource.py", 100,
>   "get", "return self.invoke(\"GET\", relpath, params, headers=headers,
>   allow_redirects=True, clear_cookies=clear_cookies)" ], [
>   "/usr/lib/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/lib/rest/resource.py", 80,
>   "invoke", "clear_cookies=clear_cookies)" ], [
>   "/usr/lib/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/lib/rest/http_client.py", 196,
>   "execute", "raise self._exc_class(ex)" ] ] }"

any suggestions to resolve this issue?
Thanks in advance

Comment: The standard practise is to redirect all Stdout / Stderr to a local file, then upload it to HDFS for debugging purposes. Not to let it flow to the YARN logs and clutter Oozie post-processing.

Comment: And what are these `/sbin/stop` and `/sbin/start` oddities?

Comment: Thanks!.  /sbin/stop and /sbin/start for restarting oozie in EMR